# Why is my for loop becoming an infinite loop here?

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

I have this code right now:

```
void performAction(int n){
  int i;
  int returnValue;
  pthread_t p;

  for(i=1; i < n; i++){
    printf("Iteration %d",i);
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, donothing, NULL);
    pthread_join(p, (void**)&returnValue);
    if(returnValue == 0){
      printf("Terminated");
    }
  }
}

void* donothing(){
  pthread_exit ((void*)0);
}
```

My task is to start n processes with pthread create and immediately join them, to wait for their termination.

I get to the `printf("Terminated");` after every "Iteration %d", but it never seems to increment.

Right now all I get is an infinite loop of this output:

```
Iteration 1
Terminated
Iteration 1
Terminated
...
```

Why is this a infinite loop here? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Your pthread routine should take a single `void*` argument, rather than an unknown argument list.

Comment: There's really no point in creating a thread and joining with it immediately. Your level of concurrency remains exactly 1.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart looks like *toy code* to me, just for getting a grip with the *pthreads* API. For that purpose, it's ok ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes, that's correct. I'm trying to get used to threading in unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

culprit is probably this line:

```
pthread_join(p, (void**)&returnValue);
```

you cast a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `void *`. Let me guess, you're on *amd64*? `void *` takes 8 bytes then, while `int` takes 4 bytes. So you're probably overwriting your `i` in the same stack frame.

The right thing would be to declare `void *returnValue` and call it like this:

```
pthread_join(p, &returnValue);
```

Then you can for example check `(int)returnValue`.

Comment: Quite right.  Always be suspicious when you see casting.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I should read up a bit more on void pointers.

Comment: @Sossenbinder not just void pointers. Read up on aliasing. In this case, you experience strange bugs trying to alias to a type with (potentially) different storage size.